# PDO insert statement error - parameter 1 to be string not array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am converting all mysql coding to PDO and am receiving this error -

**Warning: PDO::exec() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in**

Below is the code:

```
$ent_date = $array[1];
$ent_time = $array[2];
$card_no = $array[3];

try {
    $att = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=att', 'root', '');
    $att->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $att1 = 'insert into att_detail (att_date,att_time,att_card_no) values (:date_ent,:time_ent,:cardno)';
    $att -> exec(array(
                        ':date_ent'=>$ent_date,
                        ':time_ent'=>$ent_time,
                        ':cardno'=>$card_no));
     echo "new record created";
    }
catch (PDOException $e){
                        echo $att . "<BR>" . $e->getMessage();
                     }

$att = null;
```

Appreciate any help in understanding the quickest way to resolve.

Comment: Are you sure you read `exec` manual?

Comment: @u_mulder yes but not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: `exec` executes a query, argument to this function is a __string__.

Comment: @u_mulder yes and how do I get an array value?

Comment: You're too lazy to read a manual, right?

Comment: @u_mulder Before posting I did search, read couple of queries on stackoverflow and I suppose some manual from php.net.  Could not figure so asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` executes a query, argument to this function is a **string**.

So in a simple manner `exec` can be used with query text with **no placeholders**:

```
$att1 = 'insert into att_detail (att_date,att_time,att_card_no) ...';
$att -> exec($att1);
```

To use prepared statements you need to follow the manual and use [PDOStatement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) object:

Your code will look like (simplified version):

```
$att1 = 'insert into att_detail (att_date,att_time,att_card_no) values (:date_ent,:time_ent,:cardno)';
$stmt = $att->prepare($att1);
$stmt->execute(array(
    ':date_ent'=>$ent_date,
    ':time_ent'=>$ent_time,
    ':cardno'=>$card_no
));
echo "new record created";
```

Also, make sure you understand difference between [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php) and [`execute`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php).

Comment: I had used execute() and it didnt work so tried exec().  Then I did a couple trial & error after reading couple of docs still did not work.  It works now.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are Using `exec` which doesn't accept an array here is the manual  [PDO::exec php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)

I think that you want to use `execute` instead which accepts an array of parameters to be bound here is the manual [PDO::execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $att->prepare($att1);

$result = $stmt->execute(array(
                        ':date_ent'=>$ent_date,
                        ':time_ent'=>$ent_time,
                        ':cardno'=>$card_no));
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. Also, make sure to format your code at the top.

Comment: Thanks, @BalagurunathanMarimuthu. You are correct, and this is not my usual style of answering.